# em-based min-width media query overriding previous styles regardless of screen size

Tags: css, sass

I am building a site with [zurb foundation for sites](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/media-queries.html), and have come upon this problem: When I want to override some styles for the tablet layout, I am also overriding the styles for mobile. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

my css:

```
.footer {
    background-color: #FF7338;
    }
}

/*
LANDSCAPE PHONE
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 40em) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .footer {

    }
}

/*
TABLET
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64em) { 
    .footer {
        background-color: pink;
    }
}
```

If I inspect the site in chrome, the footer is pink at every phone (starting from 320px), and tablet(starting at 768px).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since most today's phones has a much higher pixel amount, this might be the reason. Have you checked what the phone you test on has?

Answer (score 0):

The way I build media queries is:

No media query for small screens, as I build the site mobile-first, so this is the default styling.

Then, the media queries I use in stylesheet are:

```
/* MEDIA QUERIES */  
/* for 768px screens or more */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
...
}

/* for 1024px screens or more */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
...
}
```

So I can set styles for tablets and desktops.  I use pixels for media query settings, but it is ok to use ems instead.

In summary, you need to change the way you do your media queries.  At the moment, the two you have are too similar to each other.

Comment: the problem is that these mixins are predefined in foundation - so if I use their classes for layout (small, medium, large etc), it would make sense to also use their screen-size definitions? The issue is that the classes work properly, while these styles do not